# calculate midpoint on path arc using 2 points and radius of arc

Tags: javascript, math, svg, geometry, computational-geometry

**find midpoint M of an path arc from A to B:**

diagram:

[image]

i have :

1. point A(x,y)
2. point B(x,y)
3. radius of the arc

i tried following code but **getPointAtLength** is deprecated.

```js
var myarc = document.getElementById("myarc");

// Get the length of the path
var pathLen = myarc.getTotalLength();
console.log(pathLen);
// How far along the path to we want the position?
var pathDistance = pathLen * 0.5;
console.log(pathDistance);
// Get the X,Y position
var midpoint = myarc.getPointAtLength(pathDistance)
console.log(myarc.getAttribute("d"));
console.log(midpoint);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getPointAtLength

Comment: It just moved to the base class. I've edited the documentation to remove the deprecation warning.

Comment: yes the post is changed now. thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Geometric calculation:

Сalculalate vector

```
AB = B - A   (AB.x = B.x - A.x, similar for Y)
```

It's length

```
lAB = sqrt(AB.x*AB.x + AB.y*AB.y)
```

Normalized vector

```
uAB = AB / lAB
```

Middle point of chord

```
mAB = (A + B)/2
```

Arrow value

```
F = R - sqrt(R*R - lAB*lAB/4)
```

Now middle of arc:

```
M.x = mAB.x - uAB.Y * F
M.y = mAB.y + uAB.X * F
```

Note that there are two points (you need to know circle center orientation relatice to AB), for the second one change signs of the second terms

Comment: thanks for answer. getPointAtLength is not  deprecated so i can use my previous code.

Comment: What is `M.x` and `M.y`?

Comment: @doox911 Corrected formula.